# Make WebStart Java desktop application to start on system startup on Windows and Mac

Tags: java, windows, macos, java-web-start, autostart

I developed small cross-platform (Windows and Mac) SWT desktop application. It is distributed with WebStart. So far so good, everything works.

I've got a new requirement to make my app start on system startup (with no user interaction). What is the best way to accomplish that?

In JNLP file I've got this:

```
<shortcut online="false">
    <desktop/>
    <menu submenu="CompanyName"/>
</shortcut>
```

On Windows WebStart creates a desktop link `[app_name].lnk` and it points to
`javaws.exe` and then some Java cache file as a parameter with funny name like `..\Sun\Java\Deployment\cache\6.0\4\2c0a6a781-213476`. I can possibly programmatically find that link on user's machine by name... erm... and then copy it into user's `Startup` folder. I can see a problem here though as user can disable WebStart desktop shortcut creation option all together.

On Mac WebStart pops up a dialog to prompt user for the location where to create an `[app_name].app` (user is allowed to change link name there!) file that launches an application. On Mac I don't event know where the `Startup` folder is located ([and it seems to be much more complex there](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPSystemStartup/Articles/CustomLogin.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002134-SW2)).

Is there Java library out there that abstracts *start app on system startup* concept on different platforms as SWT does for GUI abstraction?

Answer (score 3):

There is, but it's very new, so it's not widely available.

The [IntegrationService](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/javaws/developersguide/examples.html#IntegrationService) was introduced in 1.6.0u18. The method of interest is [requestShortcut](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/jre/api/javaws/jnlp/javax/jnlp/IntegrationService.html#requestShortcut(boolean,%20boolean,%20java.lang.String)).

Comment: I don't see anything related to *application autostart on system startup* in there, was it a right link?

Comment: try requestShortcut(true,true,"Startup")

Comment: anybody tried this method? does it work for mac os x too? if so, what to put there instead of "Startup"?

Answer (score 1):

You can take a look at [Java Service Wrapper](http://wrapper.tanukisoftware.org/doc/english/download.jsp). This can wire your program as a windows service.

Answer (score 0):

Bump!

Seems like http://yajsw.sourceforge.net/ is the currently active project that achieves this.